# How to define a Delphi class from XML message

Tags: xml, delphi, wsdl

I'm working with Delphi 2007.

With the WSDL importer I created, from an external WSDL, a unit which contains several functions.

Unfortunately it does not contain explicit result types for the XML returned.

F.i. the function getHash('login', 'password') return the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="...........>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:getHashResponse>
      <return xsi:type="ns2:Map">
        <item>
          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">code</key>
          <value xsi:type="xsd:string">1004</value>
        </item>
        <item>
          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">error</key>
          <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Login was not successfull</value>
        </item>
      </return>
    </ns1:getHashResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

From this I have been trying to define the correct class.
What I've come up with so far is:

```
  TKeyValue = class;

  TArrayofKeyValue = array of TKeyValue;

  TKeyValue = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FKey: String;
    FValue: String;
  published
    property Key:        String        read FKey     write FKey;
    property Value:      String        read FValue   write FValue;
  end;

  function getHash(const uid: WideString; const pwd: WideString): TArrayOfKeyValue; stdcall;
```

When I test with this code I do get two instances of TKeyValue back. But they're both empty.
What is wrong with my class definition? Or am I going about it the wrong way?

Best would be a better WSDL, but that is not up to me.

Comment: Can you try to include more complete code? What does `getHash()` do? I'm guessing your problem is inside that function.

Comment: Also, I see you have `stdcall;` at the end, indicating you're probably trying to call this in a DLL. If this is a DLL and you're trying to call this function from outside the DLL, this is critically important, because this function will not work from a DLL. Rather, the result should be in a `var` parameter and the function result should be a `bool` or an `integer` for success.

Comment: It's part of a SOAP-XML webservice. I call the function getHash, the return XML above I caught in the THTTPRIO1.onAfterExecute.

Comment: I don't know much about SOAP, sorry.

Comment: You have to use WideString instead of string in your TKeyValue class

Comment: I changed it to WideStrings but that didn't change the outcome.